in odoo 16 problem at confirm button in select product in stock_barcode module
I am working in the module stock_barcode
I try to edit the product_selector on case Confirm buttom
First I try this code to change the confirm button like this
    <record id="stock_move_line_product_selector_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">stock.move.line.product.selector.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">stock.move.line</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock_barcode.stock_move_line_product_selector"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='fixed-bottom']//button[@class='btn btn-primary o_save']" position="replace">
                <button name="custom_save_method" string="save" type="object" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
    

and I add python code code
class StockMoveLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.move.line'


   def write(self, vals):
        
        return super(StockMoveLine, self).write(vals)

    def custom_save_method(self):
        // Code here 
        return _self.write({})

when I try topress confirm button It will going to the write function
before It going to the custom_save_method function
so I can't write my code in custom_save_method method becouse I want to make case to stop saving the data
and when I try to write code in "write" method , It will applied any where with the model 'stock.move.line'
how can I make the code know if the confirm order came from the product_selector view or not
Plese any one help me in this issue
